# Hibernate: FetchMode and org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path:

Tags: hibernate

- UserFullTest has a collection of associatedTestContentElementResponses
- Each TestContentElementResponse in turn has a collection of associatedResponseAttributes

I want to pull all data in a single fetch.

Here is my code:

```
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria c=session.createCriteria(UserFullTest.class);
        c.createAlias("associatedTestContentElementResponses", "tcer");
        c.setFetchMode("tcer", FetchMode.JOIN);

        c.add(Restrictions.idEq(uftId));
        Criteria cra=c.createCriteria("tcer.associatedResponseAttributes");
        cra.createAlias("tcer.associatedResponseAttributes", "ra");
        cra.setFetchMode("ra", FetchMode.JOIN);
        List<UserFullTest> uftList = c.list();
```

I get the following Exception:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path: associatedTestContentElementResponses.associatedResponseAttributes

Any tips would be much appreciated

I should explain...
If I don't specify the subCriteria FetchMode it uses Select mode. So I am trying to get everything is a single fetch by including the sub criteria. I know the exact size of the data pull so I know a single fetch is best practice here

Answer (score 0):

The way you are creating criteria need to be changed as follows.

```
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria c=session.createCriteria(UserFullTest.class).createCriteria("tcer.associatedResponseAttributes");
    c.createAlias("associatedTestContentElementResponses", "tcer");
    c.setFetchMode("tcer", FetchMode.JOIN);

    c.add(Restrictions.idEq(uftId));

    c.createAlias("tcer.associatedResponseAttributes", "ra");
    c.setFetchMode("ra", FetchMode.JOIN);
    List<UserFullTest> uftList = c.list();
```

Comment: This brings back a 0 size list which is incorrect. UserFullTest has 15 responses and each response has two response attributes.